# Python - AI 102 - NameError: name 'image_file' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to run thru the azure ai 102 exercises and i have very limited python background. while running thru the exercises, i have run into an issue that may be a typo?

```
File "C:\GIT\AI-102-AIEngineer\15-computer-vision\Python\image-analysis\image-analysis.py", line 55, in <module>
    with open(image_file, mode="rb") as image_data:
              ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'image_file' is not defined
```

i suspect its not seeing the street jpg  from line 22 + so i have been trying to edit the
as per the insert, i have gone back to line 22 and tried to edit the line with the following variants, with no luck:

`image_file = '\\15-computer-vision\\Python\\image-analysis\\images\\street.jpg'`

`image_file = load.image("street.jpg")`

`image_file = 'C:/GIT/AI-102-AIEngineer/15-computer-vision/Python/image-analysis/image-analysis.py'`

(Any ideas would be so welcome as i have hit a wall for the past 24 hours)

how do i verify the variable `image_file` has imported the image while using visual studio code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error suggests is that the variable 'image_file' was not declared/defined in the current scope.